# UIPickerView inside a Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uipickerview, uipickerviewdelegate

I have a custom UITableViewCell where I have a UIPickerView inside it. To manage that, I've created a Subclass where I implemented the UIPickerView delegate and datasource methods. When the cellForRowAtIndexPath I implemented like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.section==2) {

        PickerCellTableViewCell *cell2=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"pickerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell2.cellPickerInputArray=self.pickerArray;

        return cell2;

    }else{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"normalCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text=[[self.inputArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

    }
}
```

on the subclass .m file I have the following:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        return [self.cellPickerInputArray count];

}
```

I have the following problem: If I leave it like this, it crashes and the console gives me this:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

However, if I change the *numberOfRowsInComponent*: to return the actual number of rows (7 in this example), everything works pretty good.

I've been trying but I don't see to find the problem/solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit! As sugested by @meda I NSLoged `NSLog(@"PickerInputArray count"%@",[self.cellPickerInputArray` count]); inside the method *pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent*

Here:

```
2014-03-30 21:04:54.756 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count0
2014-03-30 21:04:54.757 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count0
2014-03-30 21:04:54.758 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count0
2014-03-30 21:04:54.758 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count0
2014-03-30 21:04:54.762 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count7
2014-03-30 21:04:54.765 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count7
2014-03-30 21:04:54.767 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count7
2014-03-30 21:04:54.770 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count7
2014-03-30 21:04:54.771 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count7
2014-03-30 21:04:54.771 TestPickerOnTable[3498:60b] PickerInputArray count7
```

Comment: Log it `NSLog(@"PickerInputArray count"%@",[self.cellPickerInputArray count]);` if it's not equal to 7 you will need to find out whyt

Comment: Yeah, tried that already. See edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logs, it seems that the number of elements in your `UIPicker` data source changes.

When you add or delete an element from `self.inputArray`  always make sure you reload the components or you will get the invalid update error.

to reload the picker:

```
[_yourPicker reloadAllComponents]
```

Comment: self.inputArray is a static array, it doesn't change. What I also don't understand is why "numberOfRowsInComponent" is called 10 times...

Comment: Yeah i notice that,did you mean to return that cell for every row of section 2?

Comment: No. Also when the inputArray contents 16 items, the number of time this picker method is called are the same: 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question two years ago, so you've probably already solved it, but the problem is that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you create two different kind of cells depending on the value of `IndexPath.section`.

`if indexPath.section == 2`, your (custom) cell has a `cellPickerInputArray`. Otherwise, your (normal) cell doesn't have that, so your `numberOfRowsInComponent` fails because there is now array to get the count of.

To fix this, change your `numberOfRowsInComponent` to have the same `if..then..else` structure:

```
if (indexPath.section==2) {
  return [self.cellPickerInputArray count];
} else {
  return <some appropriate value>;
}
```